# Error instantiating properties of an exported class

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express

I'm trying to instantiate an exported class, but I'm getting the following error:

> TypeError: Cannot set property '_db' of undefined

How I am creating and exporting the class:

```
const mongodb = require('mongodb').MongoClient
const url = 'mongodb://localhost/via'
const collection = 'images'

module.exports = class DB {
    constructor() {
        mongodb.connect(url, function(err, db) {
            if (err) throw err

            this._db = db.db('via') //Error line

            this._db.createCollection(collection, function(err, res) {
                if (err) throw err
                console.log(`Collection ${collection} created successfully.`)
            })
        })
    }
}
```

How I am instantiating:

```
const db = require('../db/images')
let database = new db();
```

I've tried creating the variable before using it, but to no avail. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Your `mongodb.connect` is not using an arrow function callback,  so `this` will not be the `this` you expect..   try -> `mongodb.connect(url, (err, db) => { ...`

Comment: @Keith Write ^ as an answer instead. I'll upvote it.

Comment: @Francisco Unrelated, but you should probably pass in `collection` into the constructor as well. This way you can use this code for any collection and not just images.

Comment: @Keith This works, thanks a lot! May you can make a answer to help future people with same problem. Why not?

Comment: @ralphtheninja I didn't thought that. Thx for suggestion.

Comment: @ralphtheninja Done now, was on mobile before so didn't want to make a proper answer until on PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that your constructor where your calling `mongodb.connect` your using a normal function callback -> `function(err, db)` this means anything inside the function `this` won't be pointing to your class.

One simple solution to this is use the arrow function, replace `function(err, db) {` with `(err, db) => {`

Personally I'm not a big fan of arrow functions, in some respects I see it like the `with` statement, it's easy to loose context.  So another way, that works with arrow function & normal functions is to capture scope.

For example ->

```
module.exports = class DB {
    constructor() {
        const thisDB = this;
        mongodb.connect(url, function(err, db) {
            if (err) throw err

            thisDB._db = db.db('via') //Error line

            thisDB._db.createCollection(collection, function(err, res) {
                if (err) throw err;
                //bonus, thisDB will work here too.
                console.log(`Collection ${collection} created successfully.`)
            })
        })
    }
}
```

Above it's obvious what `thisDB` points too, and when doing even deeper level callbacks it will still be valid as shown above where I've mentioned `bonus, thisDB will work here too`